# Launching Android Open Source SDK from Eclipse in Linux

Tags: android

I have downloaded Android Open Source Project and build it in Linux from `command line`. All are  fine. I can use the emulator.

I installed also Eclipse and AVD via eclipse. Now I want to use the open source emulator that I build from command line. How can I do that?

Mahbub

Answer (score 0):

From the shell in which you build AOSP you can run `emulator` and it will start an emulator which it built as part of AOSP along with the system image created in your AOSP build.  You can also use the SDK provided emulator by passing it command line arguments for the kernel, init RAM disk, system partition and data partition.

Comment: I want to use the same emulator from Eclipse that I built from command line, can I do that? If yes what are the steps?

Comment: I don't exactly follow what you mean.  Eclipse/ADT comes with pre-built emulator executables which use pre-built Android system images and kernels.  When you build AOSP you get your own copies of these as part of your build results.  If you wish to use Eclipse/ADT's AVD to run an Android build you created, the easiest way would be to create a new AVD then manually edit the specific AVD config file to use the init RAM disk, system image and user data image produced by your AOSP build.

Comment: Thanks, you got what I meant I want to use Eclipse with my own AVD that I build from command line. I don't see any way to associate the emulator from AVD manager. I like to use full source code and step in as necessary. I found a way to attach source code to Eclipse probably that is an alternative solution for me.

Comment: You shouldn't need the emulator executable itself to step and debug Android platform code. It is just qemu with some special changes made to it and Android isn't aware of it at all - it thinks it is just running on a machine.  The key is to modify the AVD configuration after you have created it so that it points to your system image, etc.  Look in ~/.android/avd for your specific AVD directory.  In there you will find a hardware-qemu.ini and config.ini.  Edit these as needed to use your system, user data and init ramdisk images.